# How to execute a local Shell Script with SSH commands on server?

Tags: php, bash, shell, ssh

I want to run a local shell script that have SSH commands on the server using PHP. And inside the script i am using `ssh` to run a command like `ls -lart` and save the result on a log file in the server, and then using `scp` to copy the remote file to my local host. Something like this:

```
/// my_local_shell.sh

#!/bin/bash
host=$1
user=$2
port=$3
ssh -p $port $user@$host 'ls -lart >> /home/remote/file.log'
scp -P $port $user@$host:/home/remote/file.log /home/local/file.log
```

If i run the script using the terminal `user@local_host:~$ ./my_local_shell.sh` everything works just fine. But if i use `shell_exec()` to execute the script using PHP like this:

```
/// index.php

$output = shell_exec("my_local_shell.sh 192.168.1.1 root 2222");
echo <pre>$output</pre>;
```

Nothing is printed on screen and the SSH commands inside the file are not executed.
I know I can use `ssh2_shell()`, but by using it I would have to send the commands inside the PHP, and it's not what i want.
I already gave the permissions needed to `index.php` and `my_local_shell.sh`

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Is php run with the same user as the one you tried?

Comment: Yes, same user.

Comment: If you are running the script through the webserver, then the script is run with the same user as the webserver, typically called http or www-data. Try through CLI first. Also check the php.ini for disabled functions.

Comment: I've tried already. It doesn't show any errors or warnings and doesn't work too. When i tried to write the result of ssh command on a local file directly, it creates the log file(user www-data) but with nothing in it.

Comment: Try exec, you can pass a parameter to be filled with output:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Already tried. Same results.

Comment: Are you trying to check if the command succeeds or you want to output the result from the ls command? Because if it's the latter, you don't have an output command in your shell script

Comment: I want to output the result of the command in a file.`ls -lart >> /home/remote/file.log`. This commando should be executed on the server, that is, the file `file.log` would be created on the remote host.

Comment: I'm assuming that your shell script works fine, so if the php script runs from terminal but not from the webserver IMHO it can be only the user or the php.ini as already suggested.

Comment: I'll check my php.ini. The php script doesn't work properly from terminal too.

Comment: I can't think of anything else, look at this if it can help https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/
Also, some framework like ZEND have additional security function, but you didn't tell us anything about your setup, so it's just a conjecture

Comment: Just checked my php.ini. Everything is ok. No relevant functions disabled. I've seen a few frameworks that does it. But I want to do it myself. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you done some basic troubleshooting? First thing, is the shell script even being run? I notice you aren't calling it with an absolute path name, which you should be.

Comment: Yes. It works fine if a don't use any ssh commands on my shell script. The problems occurs only when I try to use ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently scp uses some sort of ncurses that you can't capture, so you could add the -v flag to your scp command in the shell script

```
scp -v -P $port $user@$host:/home/remote/file.log /home/local/file.log
```

or alternatively, since scp returns 0 on success you could write

```
scp -P $port $user@$host:/home/remote/file.log /home/local/file.log && echo Success
```

As for the PHP please check you have PHP opening and closing tags and correct your echo statement

```
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

Comment: It will not work because the previous command (`ssh -p $port $user@$host 'ls -lart >> /home/remote/file.log' `) will be a failure and will not create the log file. If I don't use SSH commands everything works just fine. But I want to retrieve the information from the remote host, so I have to use SSH. My echo is correct, I just type it wrong here...

Comment: Ok for the echo, but what do you mean that ssh will fail? Did you setup a key-based login? Are the path you specified correct?

Comment: Yep. I can login via terminal without password normally. And if I only use other commands on my shell script it works.